# Two similar MySQL queries give different results

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database that holds readings for devices. I am trying to write a query that can select the latest reading from a device. I have two queries that are seemingly the same and that I'd expect to give the same results; however they do not. The queries are as follows:

First query:

```
select max(datetime), reading
from READINGS
where device_id = '1234567890'
```

Second query:

```
select datetime, reading
from READINGS
where device_id = '1234567890' and datetime = (select max(datetime)
                                               from READINGS
                                               where device_id = '1234567890')
```

The they both give different results for the reading attribute. The second one is the one that gives the right result but why does the first give something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is MySQL behaviour at work. When you use grouping the columns you select must either appear in the group by or be an aggregate function eg min(), max(). Mixing aggregates and normal columns is not allowed in most other database flavours.

The first query will just return the first rating in each group (first in the sense of where it appears on the file system), which is most likely wrong.

The second query correlates rating with maximum time stamp leading to the correct result.

Comment: So if I tried the first in something like MSSQL, it'd probably puke at me and tell me I'm in error?

Comment: @Perley for the first query? quite likely, I believe only SQLite behaves in the same way as MySQL in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are not using a `GROUP BY reading` clause, which you should be using in both queries.

Comment: That doesn't work at all. It gives me something entirely different. And why would I want to use a group by when reading is not even what I'm aggregating on?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal on MySQL. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) on this:

```
If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.
```

Also, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) and [Explan extended](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html) commands to know more about your queries.